# Get RFID USB Chipreader value without textfield JAVA

Tags: java, javafx

I have been trying to work around a software to store workers time input data with RFID USB Card reader, which is successfull but only if an interface is opend(GUI) with the input textfield focused. My target now to get the input data even if the GUI is not running, because the softare will be compile to .exe file. Which will be installed on Server and will then be running as background app. any idears will realy be apprecieted. The RFID has no screen or so ever is just a sensor to capture the ID of a worker.the software as i said is running.

Comment: How does the RFID put the text it reads in the textfield? Have you tried using a scanner and the command line?

Comment: the RFID Had is own Chip  so i just need to stamp the Chip on the RFID and it gets me the Data with the help auf Java eventlistener to the textfield. after it stores the data perfect to where i want it to be. but only if the textfield is on focus, which i dont want it that way.

Comment: Will it input into a text document, like notepad? Or does it have to be into a textfield?

Comment: getting data is not a probem but  i want to get the data even if the textfield is not on focus.